# SwiperJS - I don't want that when I click on a button inside a slider, it brings that slider to the first position

Tags: javascript, carousel, swiper.js

**When I click on a button that I have inside my slider, instead of executing what the button should do, what it does is take that slider to position 1 of the carousel. what I want is that this does not happen since it does not allow the action of the button to be executed, which is to open an overlay. I leave a video so that it is better understood.**

I checked the documentation and I couldn't solve it.
This is my code:

```
let swiperTrending = new Swiper(".swiper-container-trending", {
    slidesPerGroup: 1,
    autoplay: {
        delay: 3000,
    },
    speed: 1000,
    grabCursor: true,
    navigation: {
        nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
        prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },
    breakpoints: {
        100: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 10,
        },
        768: {
            slidesPerView: 2,
            spaceBetween: 10,
        },
        1024: {
            slidesPerView: 3,
            spaceBetween: 60,
        },
    },
});
```

https://sendvid.com/rkza0bku

Comment: I'm having the same issue, when I have a anchor <a> tag, it automatically slides to the next slide, but only on the first click, 
Some say setting watchSlideProgress to true fixes the problem, but not for me.
opened issue here:https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/5437

Comment: can you fix the problem by going back to version @7